# Azure CDN Video 360 streaming

Tags: streaming, 360-degrees

I suspect Microsoft azure CDN to be to slow to stream video 360. Video 2880x1440 pixel and this is not something outstanding but bitrate relatively high - 25 Mb/s (video 360 degrees)

http://realgrad.azureedge.net/realgrad/index.html

Can anybody please check that streaming goes without delay?

Comment: it seems fine ... its streaming at about 2 to 2.5 Mb/s from my end from a connection which performs on a http://speedtest.net  of 20 Mb/s